# How to use createTransport?

Tags: haskell

I'm currently following [Cloud-Haskell tutorial](http://haskell-distributed.github.io/tutorials/tutorial2.html) and is stuck at `createTransport`.  It seems to me I'm only able to open a transport at 127.0.0.1 for server and can't open a transport for client to connect to the server.  I've tried using two machines, using `curl ifconfig.me` to get my IP address, however, `createTransport` would not create a transport for me.  Any ideas?

EDIT: locally is working now.

My program is the exact same as the tutorial, trying to connect between two machines:

`curl ifconfig.me` returns `101.119.27.24`

Command line for server:

```
ServerClientServer 101.119.27.24 9000
```

Error returned:

```
bind: unsupported operation (Cannot assign rerquested address)
```

EDIT:
  The server code is as followed:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  [host, port]    <- getArgs
  serverDone      <- newEmptyMVar
  Right transport <- createTransport host port 
  Right endpoint  <- newEndPoint transport
  forkIO $ echoServer endpoint serverDone 
  putStrLn $ "Echo server started at " ++ show (address endpoint)
  readMVar serverDone `onCtrlC` closeTransport transport
```

The `echoServer` and `onCtrlC` functions are defined in another module.

I changed the `Right transport <- createTransport host port` into

```
t <- createTransport host port defaultTCPParameters
let transport = case t of
  (Right t) -> t
  (Left e)  -> error $ show e
```

so that I can see what the error message is.

Comment: Could you provide us with some code that is failing to work as expected?  How about `createTransport iNADDR_ANY "3000" defaultTCPParameters`?

Comment: Which backend are you working with? The last time I used the project here was a back end for the local net work.  Since then I have seen a peer to peer version pop up on hackage and one or two others.

Comment: Backend as in package? network-transport-tcp-0.3.1

Comment: What I ment by back end is breifly discribed in the description at the top of the page for the 
[distributed-process](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-process).  The example they give and the one I was think of is the [simple local net backend.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-process-simplelocalnet)  I do not see that being used in the example you provided however.

Comment: I don't think distributed-process is used in this example but [the next one](http://haskell-distributed.github.io/tutorials/tutorial3.html) will use it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Haskell actually. You are behind a NAT device (such as a broadband router) and the address in question belongs to the device, not to your computer. You cannot bind to it.

Comment: I see, so how do I find my computers IP? How should I bind?

Comment: Try the `ifconfig` command (`ipconfig` on Windows). You will get an address on your local network, or several addresses on several networks (e.g. wired and wireless). If you have a typical home network connected to a broadband router, these addresses will be visible from your home network(s) but not from the Internet. To make your server accessible from the outside you need to configure a "hole" in your router. This is all basic networking stuff, you have to learn it if you want to do anything "cloudy".

Comment: @n.m. you should submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: If you do not care to bind to a specific IP address and simply want to your program to run on port 9000 whatever the IP maybe, you can use the IP `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Community-wiki answer based on comments:

You are behind a NAT device (such as a broadband router) and the address in question belongs to the device, not to your computer. You cannot bind to it.

Try the `ifconfig` command (`ipconfig` on Windows). You will get an address on your local network, or several addresses on several networks (e.g. wired and wireless). If you have a typical home network connected to a broadband router, these addresses will be visible from your home network(s) but not from the Internet. To make your server accessible from the outside you need to configure a "hole" in your router. This is all basic networking stuff, you have to learn it if you want to do anything "cloudy".